# Regular expression, How to allow combination of dot (period) and letters?

Tags: regex

I want to allow `.` and `a-zA-Z` letters and `_` and `-`,
I have some problems with the `.`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 33):

```
[A-Za-z_.-]
```

is a character class that includes all the characters you mentioned. Inside a character class, it's not necessary to escape the `.`, and you can avoid escaping the `-` if you put it first or last.

If numbers are ok, too, you can shorten this to

```
[\w.-]
```

Comment: `\w` is supported in many modern regex engines, but not universal. The longhand version will work way back to the original Thompson regex engine.

Comment: True, and depending on the regex flavor and settings, `\w` may also match Unicode letters, which may or may not be desirable.

Answer (score 6):

This will do `[a-zA-Z_.-]+`

Outside the character class, (`[]`), you need to escape the dot (`\.`)as it is a meta character.

```
[a-z]+\.com  #matches `something.com`
```

Answer (score 6):

`[a-zA-Z_\-.]`  should work. You might have to use a double slash, depending on the language you are using.

Comment: Escaping `.` isn't required inside a character class :)

Comment: ... and escaping `-` is required, unless it's the first or the last

Comment: Backslashing the dash works in some regex engines, but not all. Moving it first or last is your best bet.

Answer (score 3):

`.` Has a special meaning in regular expressions, it uses to denote any character. Therefore you need to use escape character.

So you need to use `\.`

Answer (score 1):

Escape it, as it's a special character:

```
\.
```

Answer (score -1):

As everyone already said, if you enclose a set of characters (no need to escape in this situation) in square brackets, you are saying: "please allow these characters I'm putting inside.
I found a reference video for you:
[Skip to 22-23 min](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kWyoYtvJpe4)

Answer (score -3):

This should work just fine:

```
  [A-z._\-]+
```

Please be aware that you my have to escape that slash depending on your programming language.

Comment: `A-z` will allow symbols from 91 thru 96 `[\\]^_\`` And hyphen need not be escaped if it is the first or last character in a character class